# Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form' angular 8

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have this error in console

```
Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. ("
```

, and I already added the FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule modules in app.module.ts, and the error continues

I already restarted the server and it's still the same, someone could guide me please, thanks
I already restarted the server and it's still the same, someone could guide me please, thanks

```
  <form [formGroup]="valForm" >
    </form>
```

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { CustomValidators } from "ng2-validation";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.page.scss'],
})
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {
  valForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(public fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.valForm = fb.group({
      email: [
        "ionicfirebaseapp@gmail.com",
        Validators.compose([Validators.required, CustomValidators.email])
      ],
      password: ["123456", Validators.required]
    });

   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

    import { CommonModule }  from '@angular/common';

    import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
    import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
    import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
    import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'



    import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule  } from '@angular/forms';

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent],
      entryComponents: [],
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot(),
        AppRoutingModule,
        HttpClientModule,


      ],
      providers: [
        StatusBar,
        SplashScreen,

        { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
      ],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule {}
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuard } from './_guard/auth.guard';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'folder/:id',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    loadChildren: () => import('./folder/folder.module').then( m => m.FolderPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/home/home.module').then( m => m.HomePageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'product-list/:id',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/product-list/product-list.module').then( m => m.ProductListPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'product-details',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/product-details/product-details.module').then( m => m.ProductDetailsPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'cart',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/cart/cart.module').then( m => m.CartPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'categories',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/categories/categories.module' ).then( m => m.CategoriesPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/login/login.module').then( m => m.LoginPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'register',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/register/register.module').then( m => m.RegisterPageModule)
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: Did you add `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule` to the module that your `LoginPage` is a part of?

Comment: can you include your code of your `AppRoutingModule`

Comment: Import ReactiveFormsModule in LoginPageModule